# What is the best way to take input as per testcases?

Tags: java

I want to take input as per this way. The input begins with  number of testcases x and in each of the next x lines there are two numbers m and n.
For eg:-

```
2
1 10
3 5
```

But i want to call a function after taking the input. I want to pass the input values to the function to print my output . I tried this way but it is calling the function first. 
Basically i want to take all inputs first then call the function for each test case for getting the output.
Below is the code what i tried.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int x = in.nextInt();
      for(int i=0 ; i<x ; i++) {
          int n = in.nextInt();
          int m = in.nextInt();
          PrimeFactors(n , m);
          System.out.println();
      }
}
```

Comment: First loop takes the inputs. Saves the inputs in an array. Second loop iterates over the input array and calls your function

Comment: Unrelated: in java, method names go camelCase, and should contain a verb. Like `computePrimeFactors(n, m)` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You should call function after loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = in.nextInt();
    int[][] array = new int[x][2];
    for(int i=0 ; i<x ; i++) {
        array[i][0] = in.nextInt();
        array[i][1] = in.nextInt();
    }

    for (int[] ints : array) {
        PrimeFactors(ints[0], ints[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to split the input and the algorithm.

You can just extract `PrimeFactors(n , m);` to a separate class and test in via regular unit tests.